# how can replace some of words when I added post from

Tags: php, wordpress

my friends ..

I want to design a small plugin ..

it is work is: when the user write a post for example :

**<< WordPress >> widgets are the dynamic objects which eases the customization of the content on << sidebars >> and widgetized << footers >>. << Widgets >> allows drag-n-drop interface in the Dashboard << admin panel >>, for easy << management >>.**

directly the plugins search about the words which between <<..>> then search in the db for wordpress if there a title like this word.
if it exist replace it by the url of page ..
if it not exist create a new page with some 'text .. ect' then replace the word by the url of page.

for example : when I wrote these: *<< wordpress >> widgets are the dynamic << objects >> .*
the plugins search about 'wordpress' in the title pages if it existe set the url: [wordpress](http://myblog/p21). then the plugins search about ' objects' in the title pages if it not exist the first step: create a page: object then fill it some text the final step . replace the word << objects >> , by the url of the post of object ,

I want to know how to do it.
Give me example I will try to develompe it .

Thank you very much ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php) to find the "<>" pattern and replace it.

WordPress provides a Class: [wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class) to interact with the database.

You could query the db for the title, create a link to the page, and replace the text pattern with the link.

I don't know about creating a page dinamically with a plugin though...

Comment: thank you very much .. Fernando ..

but I still wait some users to explain more and more ..

thank you very much ..